# How to include all files in a project when publishing from Powershell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to publish a .Net web app using Powershell.  I want to publish "all files in this project" but it only seems to be publishing "only files needed to run this application".  When I publish from Visual Studio 2010 it work fine.

Here's my command:

```
& msbuild "$WebProjectFile" /verbosity:minimal "/t:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication;publish" /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir="$PublishPath\bin\" /p:WebProjectOutputDir="$PublishPath"
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alistek pointed me in the right direction and I ended up using [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) to copy the missing files:

```
& robocopy "{folder with missing files}" "$PublishPath\{folder to put missing files}" /MIR /NJH /NJS /NFL /NDL
```

Notes:

- This worked perfectly for me because all my missing files were from a single directory
- The `/NJH /NJS /NFL /NDL` switches are only used to stop Robocopy from spitting its progress to the screen

Comment: Any solution without robocopy ?

Answer (score 2):

Some notes since I am not sure exactly what is not working:
 - CopyLocal set to true for all your references
 - Add a specific copy files to the your build script

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ProjectBinFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(StageBin)\%ProjectBinFiles.RecursiveDir)" />
```

Below is a similar question about not all files copying:

[MSBuild target _CopyWebApplication does not copy all necessary files to the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593987/msbuild-target-copywebapplication-does-not-copy-all-necessary-files-to-the-bin)

Not sure if any of this helps.

-Adam

[Edit: trying to undo my edit]

Comment: thx... I'm not exactly sure what to do with that code.  Where do I put it?